# Strange error with folder permissions (mkdir)

Tags: php, nginx, mkdir

I am running a nginx server and php5, but I am not able to get mkdir in php working. I always get a `permission denied` error.
The user, who is running nginx is **www** in group **www**, the same applies for php and my folder where I want to create a new one is also hold by **www**.

It only works when I set the folder permissions to 777, with 775 I can't get it working.

The curious thing is, when I try to create a folder in the terminal as **www** user it works without any issues.

Any help would be really appreciated, because I have been struggling with this error for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because problem with `PHP` module configuration. You have to set correct user there, too.

Check this [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

Comment: I already setted the user in the php-fpm.conf, do I have to change the php.ini also?